# CSS/HTML: ul:empty selector won't match an empty list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS and HTML code:

```
<ul id="actions" class="frame frame-yellowglow">
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#actions {
    clear: left;    
    width: calc(60% - 2px);
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#actions:empty {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#actions li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}
.frame {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border: 1px #dddddd solid;
}
.frame:empty {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.frame-yellowglow {
    border: 1px #D4B700 solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #D4B700;
}
```

The `ul` is populated with icons for certain actions that can be performed.  However, the `ul` does not match the :empty selector when empty and as such still renders; border, padding, shadow, and all.

[EDIT: To clarify, I'm talking here about when elements have not yet been added.  Even when there's nothing within, it still doesn't match the :empty selector. ]

Why is this so?

Comment: In what way is it populated? If the DOM object has children, it won't count as empty. Whether those elements are there due to markup or Javascript is irrelevant.

Comment: When you say "empty" do you mean it's just `<ul></ul>`?  Also, what browser are you working in (`:empty` may not be supported)?

Comment: @lonesomeday via PHP whenever the page is generated and can change via javascript.

Comment: @ASGM it's <ul></ul>. Tested in chrome and firefox

Comment: @user1363115 So you mean it's *not* empty, then? If there are elements added by Javascript, `:empty` will not match.

Comment: @lonesomeday I'm talking about in the case of there being no elements within.  If there are no elements within it still won't match `:empty`, leaving me with a border and nothing within.  No elements added yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)**

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are considered.

Your "empty" `ul` probably contains a whitespace text-node.

Comment: Wait... would a \n or \t within make it not empty?

Comment: There are no nodes, but still a newline and a few tab chars.

Comment: Actually, yes, I took out the \n\t and that made it match.  Which is awfully inconvenient as it makes the HTML source look ugly, but anyways it works.  Thank you

Comment: @Jake: Yes, `\n` and `\t` are considered whitespace for the purposes of `:empty`. It's definitely inconvenient; I believe there are proposals for a new selector that would match an element that is either empty or only contains whitespace.